# window.height() is not working ? trying to get the width of the window

Tags: jquery

i want to make a div to the height and width of the window, but the height does not work. Here is the code i have tried so far

```
<style>
.box { display:block; background:#0FC;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="box">
anc
</div>

<script>
    var height= $(window).height();
    var width=$(window).width();

    $(".box").width() = width;
    $(".box").height() = height;
</script>
```

Is there something i have done wrong? if so then could you be kind enough to show me the correct code to do so ! 
Thank you very much

Comment: `$(".box").width(width)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var height= $(window).height();
    var width=$(window).width();

    $(".box").width(width);
    $(".box").height(height);
```

Demo: - http://jsfiddle.net/YXGNW/

Answer (score 4):

First you are missing document.ready and you are using wrong statement for defining height and width.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var height= $(window).height();
    var width=$(window).width();

    $(".box").width(width);
    $(".box").height(height);

});
</script>
```

for setting `width` you need to pass it as argument.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
$(function(){
  var height= $(window).height();
  var width=$(window).width();
  $(".box").height(height);
  $(".box").width(width);
  });
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/
  http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

you dont need jquery:

```
window.innerHeight

window.innerWidth

document.body.clientWidth

document.body.clientHeight
```

document is much bigger than the window you look through onto the document